# How to track a variable's value from another class

Tags: java

I am creating a `Player` class for my game, and I need some way to track the controls, but I want to track the keyboard seperately from the player hitbox/rendering class. I have code set up to store the value of certain keys (<kbd>W</kbd>,<kbd>A</kbd>,<kbd>S</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>▲</kbd>,<kbd>◄</kbd>,<kbd>▼</kbd>,<kbd>►</kbd>) in variables, in my main class. I want to somehow point to the variables in the constructor and somehow have them tracked.

One way to solve the problem is to replace the variable `w` with `player2.up` and so on, so my keyboard tracking methods directly edit the `Player` objects, but this isn't as flexible. I could also pass the calling object to the constructor, but this is even less flexible. I will have to track the keyboard from within the player class for now, but it would be really cool to somehow reference the variables.

I've had to pass the constants supplied with the `KeyListener` interface in the mean time, but here's the code:

```
package learn_game_programming;

import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Player extends Rectangle {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6027220656827265195L;

    int upKey;
    int downKey;
    int leftKey;
    int rightKey;
    boolean up;
    boolean down;
    boolean left;
    boolean right;
    int ym;
    int xm;
    KeyboardTracker keyListener;
    Component caller;
    String name;

    public Player() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Player(Rectangle r) {
        super(r);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Player(Point p) {
        super(p);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Player(Dimension d) {
        super(d);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Player(int width, int height) {
        super(width, height);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Player(Point p, Dimension d) {
        super(p, d);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public Player(String name, int x, int y, int width, int height, int upKey, int downKey, int leftKey, int rightKey, Component caller) {
        super(x, y, width, height);
        this.upKey = upKey;
        this.downKey = downKey;
        this.leftKey = leftKey;
        this.rightKey = rightKey;
        this.keyListener = new KeyboardTracker();
        this.caller = caller;
        caller.addKeyListener(this.keyListener);
        this.name = name;
    }

    private class KeyboardTracker implements KeyListener{
        public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ke){
            int key = ke.getKeyCode();
            if(key == upKey){
                up = true;
            }
            if(key == downKey){
                down = true;
            }
            if(key == leftKey){
                left = true;
            }
            if(key == rightKey){
                right = true;
            }
        }

        public void keyReleased(KeyEvent ke){
            int key = ke.getKeyCode();
            if(key == upKey){
                up = false;
            }
            if(key == downKey){
                down = false;
            }
            if(key == leftKey){
                left = false;
            }
            if(key == rightKey){
                right = false;
            }
        }

        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent x){

        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent x){

        }

    }

    public void tick(){
        if(up){
            ym = -4;
            xm = 0;
        }
        if(down){
            ym = 4;
            xm = 0;
        }
        if(left){
            xm = -4;
            ym = 0;
        }
        if(right){
            xm = 4;
            ym = 0;
        }

        x += xm;
        y += ym;

        //System.out.println(x + ", " + y);

        if(this.y <= 25) y = 25;
        if(this.y >= caller.getHeight() - 10) y = caller.getHeight() - height;
        if(this.x <= 0) x = 0;
        if(this.x >= caller.getWidth() - 10) x = caller.getWidth() - height;
    }

    public void render(Graphics g){
        g.drawString(name, (x + width / 2) - g.getFontMetrics().stringWidth(name) / 2, y);
        g.fillOval(x , y, width, height);
    }

}
```

Comment: We can't comment on code without seeing the code.

Comment: This is not a problem to do, but it is too broad a question without any code as a context.

Answer (score 1):

As JB Nizet mentions, its hard to help without at least a working code example. But here is my crack at it. It sounds like you might want to consider implementing an observer pattern. Java provides the interface `Observer` and the class `Observable` to do so but you don't have to use them.

Here are links to the JavaDocs for the Java `Observer` and `Observable` objects, for you to study, in case you wanted to implement those:

[Observer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observer.html) JavaDoc, 
[Observable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) JavaDoc

And a link to an in depth tutorial on the subject:

[Observer and Observable tutorial](http://www.journaldev.com/1739/observer-design-pattern-in-java-example-tutorial)

Here is a very simple example of an observable class and an observer class. There are a lot of things that need to be taken into consideration that are not in this example. This is just to illustrate the concept:

```
public class MyObservableObject {
    private Collection<MyObserverObject> registeredObservers;
    private String  previousValue;
    private String  observedValue;
    private boolean isChanged;

public D(String observedValue) {
    this.observedValue = observedValue;
    registeredObservers = new LinkedList<MyObserverObject>();
    isChanged = false;
}

public boolean hasChanged() { return isChanged; }

private void setChanged() {
    isChanged = previousValue != null &&
                !previousValue.equalsIgnoreCase(observedValue);
}

public void setObservedValue(String observedValue) {
    previousValue = this.observedValue;
    this.observedValue = observedValue;
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}

public String toString() { return observedValue; }

public void addObserver(MyObserverObject observer) {
    registeredObservers.add(observer);
}

public void removeObserver(MyObserverObject observer) {
    registeredObservers.remove(observer);
}

public void notifyObservers() {
    for (MyObserverObject ob : registeredObservers) { ob.notify(this); }
}
}
```

This is a fairly straightforward setup:

- The value we want to track is the `String observedValue`
- The `Collection<MyObserverObject> registeredObservers` is fairly self-explanatory. It will contain any and all observer objects that our custom observable object will notify whenever `observedValue` is changed by calls to `setObservedValue(String)`.
- `addObserver(MyObserverObject)`, `removeObserver(MyObserverObject)`, and `notifyObservers()` all handle adding (registering), removing (unregistering), and notifying any observers of changes, respectively.

So now, lets look at a simple `MyObserverObject` that works with our observable:

public class MyObserverObject {
    private String valuedWatched;

```
public MyObserverObject() { valuedWatched = null; }

public void notify(MyObservableObject observed) {
    if (observed.hasChanged()) updateMyValueWith(observed);
}

private void updateMyValueWith(MyObservableObject observed) { valuedWatched = observed.toString(); }

public String toString() { return valuedWatched; }
}
```

This example is really straightforward. Whenever an instance of `MyObservableObject` calls it's `notifyObservers()` method, it will call the `notify(MyObservableObject)` method of all `MyObserverObject`s contained in the `Collection registeredObservers`. In this example, I've written a method that verifies that the `MyObservableObject` has changed, and if `hasChanged()` returns true, the `MyObserverObject` instance will call the `updateMyValueWith(MyObservableObject)` method.

Now, here it is in action:

```
public class App {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyObservableObject myOb = new MyObservableObject("Bob");
    MyObserver ob = new MyObserver();
    System.out.println(myOb + " " + ob); 
    myOb.addObserver(ob);
    d.setObservedValue("Dave");
    System.out.println(myOb + " " + ob);
}
}
```

Output:

```
Bob null
Dave Dave
```

I don't know if I can explain this example anymore than it explains itself :).

I am not sure if a by-the-hand walk-through was necessary, but I hope it helps. I did leave some things out of this explanation, but that is essentially how the observer thing works. In this way, one class can observe values in another in a very flexible fashion.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is way complicated. I'm looking for something that's simple and elegant like it works in C++